# Fatal error: Call to undefined method EE_Javascript

Tags: expresso-store, upgrade

I upgraded my EE to 2.9.3 and I am running Expresso-Store 1.6.3. Now I am getting an javascript error.

Fatal error: Call to undefined method Cp::set_variable() in /home2/oldspani/public_html/osd/expressionengine/third_party/store/mcp.store.php on line 65

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I found out. that  Store 1.6 I believe ends support at 2.7.3.